# I want to configure interspire email marketer bounce settings

Tags: gmail-imap, email-bounces

I'm using my gmail account for email marketing.
Now I'm stuck at configuring bounce setting for IEM.

Can any one help pointing out the right settings for that with gmail.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Bounce address:  YourAddress@Gmail.com
 * Apps users use @yourdomain.com

Bounce Server:  pop.gmail.com:995

Bounce Username:    YourAddress@Gmail.com
 * Apps users use @yourdomain.com

Type:  POP3

Uncheck AutoDetect

Check Do not validate cert

Check others and enter "/ssl" without the quotes

Test/Save Settings & Done